# Refuse to be owner of a Google Drive document

Tags: google-drive, permissions

Sometimes I get email notifications that a friend has shared a document with me. But I don't want to be part owner.

How can I refuse to be the document's owner? Can I refuse when someone is trying to share a document with me?

Answer (score 2):

If a person is maliciously adding you as an editor (or owner) to documents, you could [report the Google Drive/Docs abuse to Google](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2463296).

If it's a friend who's behaving anti-socially, tell him or her why you don't want to share/own the document. Unfortunately, in the email that's generated, I can't see any way to "refuse" the share in the email. Google Docs is not a social network, per se, where you'd find such features (ignoring requests).

From the tests I did briefly, I can only assign one "owner" of a document. An editor of a document can remove himself from the sharing. If you're just an editor, deleting the document won't remove you from having the permission (although the document doesn't show up either in the Trash or the All Items).

Answer (score 1):

You're the document's owner when **you** create that particular document, if you want to stop being the owner you might want to delete it.
On the other hand, if you want to refuse the sharing of a document created by someone else you might as well delete it from your list (by clicking on the checkbox at the left-side of the document) and then click Remove at the top.
Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I disagree with you : when you create a document on Google Docs, you can allow to the people you share with to fully edit it. Then, any one has a sort of "admin" role and can assign to any one any role (view only, edit, ...).

Comment: You're right, if you share the file with those "permissions" anyone can edit it and/or share to others. Although, you can set what permissions others have, even if you're not the owner **but** the owner has full access always (you can't change the owner's access)
To sum up: you can administer anyone while having "Can edit" permissions on the document, except the owner.

Comment: I know ... but, how can I refuse an admin's affectation. I don't wanna be the owner. Imagine, someone can create a "crappy" file and assign it to you ! There is surely an option where you revoke yourself.

Comment: You can certainly take away your own permissions for that matter. I insist that the sole owner of the file is the one who creates it. If what you want is to stop having a specific document in your google's Drive you can "delete" it. Also you can ask the owner to uncheck you as an admin.